# How to dynamically allocate an struct + pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I've been trying to find out how to store information from the user in an array of struct, but so far... Not working.

I created the struct, and inside the main I created the pointer to that struct, then I dynamically allocated that struct. But I don't really know how I'm going to get the info from the user, I mean. I know it but it's not working as expected. If I was using only an array of struct, it would be something like this...

&p[i].id //Normal

I tried to use this method but not working, idk why... The code is not completed yet...

```
//
//  7.c
//  IFTM Exercises
//
//  Created by Lelre Ferreira on 8/29/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Lelre Ferreira. All rights reserved.
//

#define size 5
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct produtos {

    int id;
    int quant;
    float vlrs;
    char nm[50];

};

void cadastroProdutos (struct produtos *p, int tamanho);
void maiorValorProdutos (struct produtos *p, int tamanho);
void maiorEstoqueProdutos (struct produtos *p, int tamanho);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){

    struct produtos *p;
    int tamanho    = 0;

    printf("Insira quantidade de produtos/itens a serem cadastrados: ");
    scanf("%d", &tamanho);
    p = (struct produtos *) malloc(tamanho   * sizeof(struct produtos));

    cadastroProdutos(p, tamanho);
    maiorValorProdutos(p, tamanho);
    maiorEstoqueProdutos(p, tamanho);

    return 0;
}

void cadastroProdutos(struct produtos *p, int tamanho){

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {

        printf("Insira o ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &p[i] -> id);
        printf("Insira o nome: ");
        scanf("%s",  p[i] -> nm);
        printf("Insira o valor: ");
        scanf("%f", &p[i] -> vlrs);
        printf("Insira a quantidade: ");
        scanf("%d", &p[i] -> quant);

    }
}

void maiorValorProdutos(struct produtos *p, int tamanho){



}

void maiorEstoqueProdutos(struct produtos *p, int tamanho){



}
```

The IDE is giving this error: Cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'int'...

Comment: you don't need &p[I]. p is not an array, it's a pointer to a struct. advance p each time you want to address a different struct. But this is still not what you want. you should have an array of pointers to structs.

Comment: Change the return type for `cadastroProdutos` to something meaningful that can indicate ***success/failure*** since you are taking *User-Input* within the function. (`int 1/0` is fine). Otherwise you have no way to respond to an input failure (which at present you are not even checking for -- always check the **return** of every input function used -- especially User-Input -- they don't always get it right...) A `void` return type is only appropriate where the function can have no side effects, like a function that simply prints information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed understanding that the `[..]` operator applied to your pointer `p` (e.g. `p[0]`) acts as a dereference making the type `struct produtos` and the `'.'` operator proper (instead of `struct produtos*` as noted in [@MilesBudnek's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151599/miles-budnek) answer.

Aside from your `'.'` or `'->'` operator problem, you seem to be missing the point on dynamically allocating. While it is fine to start with `#define size 5` allocated structs, the point of dynamically allocating memory is being able to handle your 6th struct seamlessly by reallocating additional memory on as as-needed basis to handle all your input (or until your run out of available memory).

The way you currently have your function `cadastroProdutos` written, doesn't really make a clean dynamic allocation possible (in addition to the fact it returns `void` and there is no validation of any input within it). Rather than looping `size` times within your function, you simply want to get 1-struct worth of data each time `cadastroProdutos` is called. That way you can call it as many times as needed until all your data is entered. There is no need to loop within your function, and your use of `scanf` is horribly fragile as you have no way to handle characters left in `stdin` due to a *matching failure* or simply stray characters accidentally typed, (e.g. `'a'` typed for `id`, or a name longer than `49` characters, etc.)

To resolve a majority of the problems, don't use `scanf` for User-Input, instead read all User-Input into a temporary buffer of reasonable size (e.g. `1024` characters or so) and then parse the needed information from the buffer using `sscanf`. This has the double-benefit of allowing separate validation of both the read and parse; and by using a reasonable sized buffer you eliminate the extraneous character problem (such as a cat stepping on the keyboard) by consuming a complete line of input every time.

Your `cadastroProdutos` which takes input, provides no meaningful return to indicate success/failure of the input leaving your function susceptible to *Undefined Behavior* if any one input fails. So validate EVERY user input by checking the return of the function(s) used. Of any input failure, returning `0` for *failure*, and non-zero on *success* allows you to handle any input failure back in the calling function.

(**note:** counting types should use `size_t` instead of `int`)

Putting those changes together for your `cadastroProdutos`, you could do something similar to:

```
size_t cadastroProdutos (produtos *p, size_t *tamanho)
{
    produtos tmp;       /* temporary struct */
    char buf[MAXC];     /* temporary buffer */

    /* prompt, read-line, validate parse */
    fputs ("\nInsira o ID: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%d", &tmp.id) != 1)
        return 0;   /* (failure) */

    fputs ("Insira o nome: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%49[^\n]", tmp.nm) != 1)
        return 0;

    fputs ("Insira o valor: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%f", &tmp.vlrs) != 1)
        return 0;

    fputs ("Insira a quantidade: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%d", &tmp.quant) != 1)
        return 0;

    p[(*tamanho)++] = tmp;  /* assign tmp to p[*tamanho], increment */

    return *tamanho;    /* return tamanho (success) */
}
```

(**note:** `tamanho` is passed as a pointer so its number can be updated within the function, and `0` is returned on failure, while the updated `tamanho` is returned on success allowing you a meaningful return of type `size_t`)

Avoid using *magic-numbers* in your code. You did a good job defining a constant for `size`, now just fining defining the constants you need so there are no more *magic-numbers* like `char nm[50];` with it. Doing that you could use a couple more `#define`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PROD 2      /* initial no. of struct to allocate */
#define NMSZ 50     /* max name size */
#define MAXC 1024   /* reasonable no. of chars for temporary buffer */

typedef struct {    /* a typedef used for convenience */
    int id;
    int quant;
    float vlrs;
    char nm[NMSZ];
} produtos;
```

Now all you need to do in `main()` is to declare a temporary buffer to hold the line, and `size_t` values, the total number of struct currently allocated (`allocated`) and the number filled (`tomanho`) which leads to a simple check at the start of each loop `if (tomanho == allocated)`, you know you need to `realloc` additional struct before attempting to fill any more. Your `main()` function can essentially be:

```
int main (void) {

    size_t  allocated = PROD,   /* initial number of struct to allocate */
            tomanho = 0;        /* number of allocated structs used */
    produtos *p = malloc (allocated * sizeof *p);   /* allocate */

    if (!p) {   /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-p");
        return 1;
    }

    while (cadastroProdutos (p, &tomanho)) {    /* loop validating return */
        char buf[MAXC];                         /* buffer for input (y/n) */
        if (tomanho == allocated) { /* is a realloc needed to add struct? */
            /* always realloc with a temporary pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (p, 2 * allocated * sizeof *p);
            if (!tmp) {     /* validate the reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-p");
                break;      /* realloc failed, original p still good, break */
            }
            p = tmp;        /* assign new block of mem to p */
            allocated *= 2; /* update no. of structs allocated */
        }

        fputs ("\n  add another (y/n)? ", stdout);  /* add more produtos? */
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || !(*buf == 'y' || *buf == 'Y')) {
            putchar ('\n');
            break;
        }
    }
```

At this point all your struct are filled and stored in `p` and all you need to do is whatever you need to do with your data (simply output below) and then `free()` the memory your have allocated, e.g.

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tomanho; i++)    /* loop showing stored data */
        printf ("p[%2zu] %4d  %-20s  %6.2f  %4d\n",
                i, p[i].id, p[i].nm, p[i].vlrs, p[i].quant);

    free (p);   /* don't forget to free memory you allocate */
}
```

Putting it altogether in a short example, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PROD 2      /* initial no. of struct to allocate */
#define NMSZ 50     /* max name size */
#define MAXC 1024   /* reasonable no. of chars for temporary buffer */

typedef struct {    /* a typedef used for convenience */
    int id;
    int quant;
    float vlrs;
    char nm[NMSZ];
} produtos;

size_t cadastroProdutos (produtos *p, size_t *tamanho)
{
    produtos tmp;       /* temporary struct */
    char buf[MAXC];     /* temporary buffer */

    /* prompt, read-line, validate parse */
    fputs ("\nInsira o ID: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%d", &tmp.id) != 1)
        return 0;   /* (failure) */

    fputs ("Insira o nome: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%49[^\n]", tmp.nm) != 1)
        return 0;

    fputs ("Insira o valor: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%f", &tmp.vlrs) != 1)
        return 0;

    fputs ("Insira a quantidade: ", stdout);
    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || sscanf (buf, "%d", &tmp.quant) != 1)
        return 0;

    p[(*tamanho)++] = tmp;  /* assign tmp to p[*tamanho], increment */

    return *tamanho;    /* return tamanho (success) */
}

int main (void) {

    size_t  allocated = PROD,   /* initial number of struct to allocate */
            tomanho = 0;        /* number of allocated structs used */
    produtos *p = malloc (allocated * sizeof *p);   /* allocate */

    if (!p) {   /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-p");
        return 1;
    }

    while (cadastroProdutos (p, &tomanho)) {    /* loop validating return */
        char buf[MAXC];                         /* buffer for input (y/n) */
        if (tomanho == allocated) { /* is a realloc needed to add struct? */
            /* always realloc with a temporary pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (p, 2 * allocated * sizeof *p);
            if (!tmp) {     /* validate the reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-p");
                break;      /* realloc failed, original p still good, break */
            }
            p = tmp;        /* assign new block of mem to p */
            allocated *= 2; /* update no. of structs allocated */
        }

        fputs ("\n  add another (y/n)? ", stdout);  /* add more produtos? */
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || !(*buf == 'y' || *buf == 'Y')) {
            putchar ('\n');
            break;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < tomanho; i++)    /* loop showing stored data */
        printf ("p[%2zu] %4d  %-20s  %6.2f  %4d\n",
                i, p[i].id, p[i].nm, p[i].vlrs, p[i].quant);

    free (p);   /* don't forget to free memory you allocate */
}
```

(**note:** a simple `add another (y/n)?` prompt is added to determine if the user wants to add more data)

**Example Use/Output**

Above we start with 2-allocated struct, and then proceed to enter 6 struct, forcing a reallocation to take place. An example could be:

```
$ ./bin/produtos

Insira o ID: 1
Insira o nome: John Brown
Insira o valor: 12.34
Insira a quantidade: 415

  add another (y/n)? y

Insira o ID: 2
Insira o nome: Mary Brown
Insira o valor: 23.45
Insira a quantidade: 416

  add another (y/n)? y

Insira o ID: 3
Insira o nome: Mickey Mouse
Insira o valor: 34.56
Insira a quantidade: 417

  add another (y/n)? y

Insira o ID: 4
Insira o nome: Minnie Mouse
Insira o valor: 45.67
Insira a quantidade: 418

  add another (y/n)? y

Insira o ID: 5
Insira o nome: Sam Clemens
Insira o valor: 56.78
Insira a quantidade: 419

  add another (y/n)? y

Insira o ID: 6
Insira o nome: Mark Twain
Insira o valor: 67.89
Insira a quantidade: 420

  add another (y/n)? n

p[ 0]    1  John Brown             12.34   415
p[ 1]    2  Mary Brown             23.45   416
p[ 2]    3  Mickey Mouse           34.56   417
p[ 3]    4  Minnie Mouse           45.67   418
p[ 4]    5  Sam Clemens            56.78   419
p[ 5]    6  Mark Twain             67.89   420
```

All data is properly stored, and you could have added 1000 more entries if you desired. You should also run any program that uses dynamic memory through a memory error checking program (like `valgrind` on Linux) that can tell if you have made improper use of a pointer of block of memory you don't own.

A short test redirecting the inputs from a file rather than retyping can confirm whether any memory problems exists, and using the memory checker is simple, just run your program though it, e.g.

````
$ valgrind ./bin/produtos < dat/produtos.txt
==12885== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12885== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12885== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12885== Command: ./bin/produtos
==12885==

Insira o ID: Insira o nome: Insira o valor: Insira a quantidade:
  add another (y/n)?
Insira o ID: Insira o nome: Insira o valor: Insira a quantidade:
  add another (y/n)?
Insira o ID: Insira o nome: Insira o valor: Insira a quantidade:
  add another (y/n)?
Insira o ID: Insira o nome: Insira o valor: Insira a quantidade:
  add another (y/n)?
Insira o ID: Insira o nome: Insira o valor: Insira a quantidade:
  add another (y/n)?
Insira o ID: Insira o nome: Insira o valor: Insira a quantidade:
  add another (y/n)?
p[ 0]    1  John Brown             12.34   415
p[ 1]    2  Mary Brown             23.45   416
p[ 2]    3  Mickey Mouse           34.56   417
p[ 3]    4  Minnie Mouse           45.67   418
p[ 4]    5  Sam Clemens            56.78   419
p[ 5]    6  Mark Twain             67.89   420
==12885==
==12885== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12885==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12885==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 896 bytes allocated
==12885==
==12885== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12885==
==12885== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
    ==12885== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)```


Always confirm `"All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible"` and that there are no errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.
````

Comment: Thank you Sir. I wish my professor were you. I really appreciate your help. There're some stuff in your code that I have never seen before, it's because you're in a higher level of coding than I am, although you've used some stuff in C that I have never seen before, I'm going to study your code and google some stuff.

For example the way you receive date from user, using stdin, stdout, fputs and so son... Thank you again Sir.

Comment: @LelreFerreira if you run into problems and need clarification, just drop a comment and I'm happy to help further. C is a fantastic language, and learning C is a journey -- not a race. So don't worry about it feeling daunting, you learn C the same way you eat a whale -- one byte at a time...

Answer (score 0):

`p[i]` is a `struct produtos`, not a `struct productos*`.  That means, to access its members you use the `.` operator, not `->`.  i.e.

```
printf("Insira o ID: ");
scanf("%d", &p[i].id);
printf("Insira o nome: ");
scanf("%s",  p[i].nm);
printf("Insira o valor: ");
scanf("%f", &p[i].vlrs);
printf("Insira a quantidade: ");
scanf("%d", &p[i].quant);
```

This is no different than it would be had you defined `p` as an array in `main`.  When you pass an array to a function it decays to a pointer to its first element.  For example:

```
// This passes a pointer to the first element of an
// array of produtos to cadastroProdutos
struct produtos p1[5];
cadastroProdutos(p1, 5);
// This also passes a pointer to the first element
// of an array of produtos to cadastroProdutos
struct produtos* p2 = malloc(5 * sizeof(struct produtos));
cadastroProdutos(p2, 5);
```

From the perspective of the `cadastroProdutos` function, those two calls are exactly the same.  In both cases, it just receives a pointer to the first element of an array and the size of the array.

Comment: It is always helpful to explain that the postfix `[...]` operates as a *dereference* to the pointer just as the unary `'*'` operator does. (it kind of helps it sink in)

Answer (score 0):

Run this. See the code, and you will understand:

```
//
//  7.c
//  IFTM Exercises
//
//  Created by Lelre Ferreira on 8/29/19. Fix by Mr. J CHEN
//  Copyright © 2019 Lelre Ferreira. All rights reserved.
//

#define size 5
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct produtos {

    int id;
    int quant;
    float vlrs;
    char nm[50];
};

void cadastroProdutos (struct produtos **p, int tamanho);
void maiorValorProdutos (struct produtos **p, int tamanho);
void maiorEstoqueProdutos (struct produtos **p, int tamanho);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    struct produtos **p;
    int tamanho = 0, i;

    printf("Insira quantidade de produtos/itens a serem cadastrados: ");
    scanf("%d", &tamanho);
    p = (struct produtos **) malloc(tamanho   * sizeof(struct produtos*));
    for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {
        p[i] = (struct produtos *) malloc(tamanho   * sizeof(struct produtos));
    }
    cadastroProdutos(p, tamanho);
    maiorValorProdutos(p, tamanho);
    maiorEstoqueProdutos(p, tamanho);
    for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {
        free(p[i]);
    }
    free(p);
    return 0;
}

void cadastroProdutos(struct produtos **p, int tamanho) {

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {

        printf("Insira o ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &(p[i]->id));
        printf("Insira o nome: ");
        scanf("%s",  p[i]->nm);
        printf("Insira o valor: ");
        scanf("%f", &(p[i]->vlrs));
        printf("Insira a quantidade: ");
        scanf("%d", &(p[i]->quant));
    }
}

void maiorValorProdutos(struct produtos **p, int tamanho) {

}
```

Comment: What did you change? And why?